# In Live Streaming how we can enable full screen from NodePlayerView like NodeCameraView in react-native-nodemediaclient library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, live-streaming

Anyone know how we can enable full screen from NodePlayerView like NodeCameraView

NodeCameraView In this code it shows full screen perfectly.

```
<NodeCameraView
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                ref={this.setCameraRef}
                outputUrl={`rtmp://...`}
                camera={{ cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true, }}
                audio={{ bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100 }}

                video={{
                    preset: 12,
                    bitrate: 400000,
                    profile: 1,
                    fps: 15,
                    videoFrontMirror: true,
                }}
                autopreview={true}
            />
```

NodePlayerView In this code it now show full screen

```
<NodePlayerView
                style={{
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: '#000000',
                }}
                // ref={this.playerRef}
                ref={(vp) => { this.vp = vp }}
                inputUrl={`https://.....`}
                scaleMode={'ScaleAspectFit'}
                bufferTime={300}
                maxBufferTime={1000}
                autoplay={true}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the components `NodeCameraView` and `NodePlayerView`, the `width` and `height` only accept values in pixels.

Try this in both components:

```
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
<NodePlayerView
    style={{
        width: width,
        height: height,
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
    }}
    // ref={this.playerRef}
    ref={(vp) => { this.vp = vp }}
    inputUrl={`https://.....`}
    scaleMode={'ScaleAspectFit'}
    bufferTime={300}
    maxBufferTime={1000}
    autoplay={true}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue was in NodeCameraView.